# How to up data from a second XML file in order to create a table

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XML files. One has the deal ID and another contains all the details about the deal.

File 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tgerental.xsl"?>
<Deals>
   <deal>
      <DealID>1</DealID>
      <Start_Date>2019/01/02</Start_Date>     
   </deal>
</Deals>
```

File 2

```
<DealDetails>
    <DealDetail DealID="1">
        <Contact>Mathew (8887778888)</Contact>
        <Product>Plane</Product>
        <Country>USA</Country>      
        <street>Delta Lane</street>     
    </DealDetail>
</DealDetails>
```

Using XSLT I am trying to combine the information from the two files so I can get a table like below, which is basically using id from the first file and getting information from the second file.

Now I can use XSLT to create table in HTML format, but not sure how to retrieve information from the second file.

```
DealDetails             StartDate
Mathew (8887778888)     2019/01/02
Plane (USA,Delta Lane)
```

I am using XSLT 2 and I tried the below code but it doesn't seem to work and I am getting this error

> Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the `XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction` property to enable it.

but I am not sure where to enable it. I am new to XSLT and I am just running the MXL file in the browser to view the generated HMTL.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Deals/Deal">
  <tr>
     <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="document('DealDetails.xml')/DealDetails/DealDetail[@DealID=$DealID]/Contact"/>
     </td>
     <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Start_Date"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: In XSLT 1 you have the `document` function to pull in secondary documents, you can then use XPath with predicates or a key to select the right section, in XSLT 2 or 3 you additionally have the `doc` function and using keys with a secondary document is a bit easier as the `key` function takes a third argument where you can pass the document in.

Comment: Thanks I tried it earlier but maybe I am doing something wrong..Here I added a variable <xsl:variable name="labels_info" select="document('DealDetails.xml')/DealDetails"/> and then using this code  <xsl:for-each select="Deals/deal">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$labels_info/DealDetail[@DealID=$DealID]/Contact"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Start_Date"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead. Also clarify which version of XSLT your processor supports; as Martin Honnen said, it makes a big difference here.

Comment: If you have code samples then insert them as minimal but complete samples in the question and show and explain exactly how they failed.

Comment: My apologies..I edited my question.

Comment: Please show minimal but complete samples, using a variable reference `$DealID` without showing its declarations doesn't allow us to tell whether that part of the code should work. As for the error message, which browser are you using or which other programming language are you using where you use `XsltSettings`? If the error is there then we need to see that code as well.

Comment: Sorry it was Contact not first name..Also I realized reading your comment that document is XSLT 1 and I a using XSLT 2 so should be looking into doc.

Comment: `document` exists in XSLT 1 and later, `doc` additionally in XSLT 2 and later. Inside the browser you normally have XSLT 1, however. And `XsltSettings` doesn't sound like browser side but rather like .NET.

Comment: Show your javascript code. Using activex you can set properties like this one.